# SQL How to concat two columns adding logical conditions

Tags: sql

Let's say I have a table with the following columns:

```
+------+------+------+
| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
+------+------+------+
| A    | A    | .    |
| B    | .    | B    |
| C    | .    | .    |
+------+------+------+
```

If I concat Col2 with Col3 I'm getting this result:

```
+------+--------+
| Col1 | Col2+3 |
+------+--------+
| A    |   A.   |
| B    |   .B   |
| C    |   ..   |
+------+--------+
```

But the desired result would be the following:

```
+------+--------+
| Col1 | Col2+3 |
+------+--------+
| A    |    A   |
| B    |    B   |
| C    |    .   |
+------+--------+
```

How could I do that?

`{UPDATE}` What I've tried so far:

`SELECT Col1, COALESCE(NULLIF(Col2,'.'),NULLIF(Col3,'.')) FROM` db`.table;`

It works partially: If Col2 = '.' and Col3 = '.' the result is [NULL] and the desired output would be '.', not '..' and not [NULL]

Comment: Are those really points in your column? Or is it NULL or an empty string?

Comment: Hi @juergend, those are really points!

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are couple of option avaiable to check null and select value which is not null for E.g :

```
 Case Condition 

CASE  
WHEN (Col2 IS NOT NULL) THEN Col2  
WHEN (Col3 IS NOT NULL) THEN Col3  
ELSE '.'  
END
```

another option

```
COALESCE(Col2, Col3) AS [Col2+3]
```

** you may need to change syntax as per your usage above syntax for just an example.

Comment: Is there any way to make a custom 'COALESCE'. Instead of choosing the first not null element, choose the first != '.' element?

Answer (score 0):

Here is way to do this concatenate the two columns and replace dot with empty string, after that if its blank/empty_string(happens when both columns have dots),then replace it with a single dot

```
select col1
       ,case when replace(concat(col2,col3),'.','')='' then
                  '.' 
             else replace(concat(col2,col3),'.','') 
         end as col2_3
  from table
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just add an ISNULL to your solution

```
SELECT Col1
    , ISNULL( COALESCE(NULLIF(Col2,'.'),NULLIF(Col3,'.')) , '.')
FROM table
```

Answer (score 0):

You are already using `COALESCE()`.  Just add another argument:

```
SELECT Col1,
       COALESCE(NULLIF(Col2,' .'), NULLIF(Col3, '.'), '.')
FROM db.table;
```

If the first two arguments are `NULL`, then it will return `'.'`.